# How to find the angle by a triangle and a median and bisector?

Tags: euclidean-geometry

The problem is as follows:

In a triangle $\triangle{ABC}$, the measure of angle $\angle ABC = \angle 105^{\circ}$. On $AC$ it is located a point $M$, such that $AB = MC$. The mediatrices of $BC$ and $AM$ intersect at $Q$. Find the measure of $\angle BAC$, if the measure of $\angle BCA = \angle ACQ$.

The alternatives given in my book are as follows:

$\begin{array}{ll}
1.&30^{\circ}\\
2.&40^{\circ}\\
3.&45^{\circ}\\
4.&35^{\circ}\\
4.&50^{\circ}\\
\end{array}$

Can someone help me with the right interpretation of this problem?. I'm having difficulties with the right drawing.

I found this problem in my book in the chapter of triangle congruency thus I believe the approach for this problem is intended to follow such route. **Can someone help me with that?**. Please **include a drawing in the answer so I can understand**. I'm lost if this requires some sort of construction. Please try to include a solution explained step-by-step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Before we dig into this question, note that I don't draw the mediatrices to avoid making the picture too complicated.

Connect $\overline{BQ}$. Let $\angle BCA=\angle ACQ=\theta$.

Since $Q$ is on the perpendicular bisector of $\overline{BC}$, we have $\color{blue}{\overline{BQ}=\overline{CQ}}$.

Since $Q$ is on the perpendicular bisector of $\overline{AM}$, we have $\color{red}{\overline{AQ}=\overline{MQ}}$.

Also from the question we already know $\color{purple}{\overline{AB}=\overline{MC}}$.

Hence $$\triangle BAQ\cong\triangle CMQ\quad(S.S.S.)$$
so $$\angle ABQ=\angle MCQ=\theta$$

We also have $$\angle QBC=\angle QCB=2\theta$$ since $\triangle BCQ$ is an isosceles. Therefore we can say $$\theta+2\theta=105^{\circ}\implies \theta =35^{\circ}$$

Finally $$\angle BAC=180^{\circ}-105^{\circ}-\theta=\color{red}{40^{\circ}}$$

Comment: Howdy! Your drawings are neat. However upon looking at the official answer it says that is $45^{\circ}$. Could it be that's a typo in the book?. I read at your solution and there isn't any flaw from what I can see. Thus I'm accepting your solution. Can you help me with [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3916662/how-to-find-the-side-of-a-triangle-which-is-connected-by-two-bisectors) and [also this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3916667/how-to-find-the-angle-formed-by-an-isosceles-triangle-next-to-another-one)? with special attention to the later.

Comment: @ChrisSteinbeckBell For the first question, unfortunately I have no clue at all. For the second one, I will check it out later.