# How to find the side of a triangle which is connected by two bisectors?

Tags: euclidean-geometry

The problem is as follows:

> Using the figure from below: Find $PR$. Assume $QS=SR$ and $PQ=24\,cm$
> and $TR=8\,cm$.

[image: Sketch of the problem]

The alternatives given in my book are as follows:

$\begin{array}{ll}
1.&\textrm{16 cm}\\
2.&\textrm{32 cm}\\
3.&\textrm{30 cm}\\
4.&\textrm{24 cm}\\
4.&\textrm{18 cm}\\
\end{array}$

This problem has left me confused. I don't know how to use the bisector identities if should they be used here or the triangle congruency. In this particular problem I'm stuck at the very beginning thus I don't know what to do.

Can someone help me here?. As mentioned I think this problem can and should be resolved using triangle congruency but I don't know which of those cases applies in this particular situation. Can someone help me with that?. **Please include a drawing in your answer** this part is difficult for me and I don't understand. Can you please include a *step-by-step* solution as I am slow at catching up from reading just lines and maybe this problem requires construction.